# Get selected item in asp dropdownlist from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

I have an asp drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="select_install_type" name="select install type">
                          <asp:ListItem Values="0" id ="installTypeMeterAndTransmitter" />   
                           <asp:ListItem Values="1" id ="installTypeTransmitterOnly" /> 
                            <asp:ListItem Values="2" id="installTypeMeterOnly"/>
                         </asp:DropDownList>
```

whose items I poplate at the server side, with localized names:

```
private void FillInstallTypeControl()
        {
            this.select_install_type.Items[0].Text = CultureResourceHelper.GetConst("meter_and_transmitter");
            this.select_install_type.Items[1].Text = CultureResourceHelper.GetConst("transmitter_only");
            this.select_install_type.Items[2].Text = CultureResourceHelper.GetConst("meter_only");
        }
```

Now I want to write a simple jquery method to run when the selection changed,
and according to the new selection do something:

```
            $('#select_install_type').change(function () {

                select_install_type.
                var selected = ($("#select_install_type").val());
              }
```

I can get the selected value, but since it is localized I do not want to compare its text against some string like so:

```
if (selected == "אאאא")
{ //Do something
}
```

How can I know which of the items were chosen? maybe get the selected index or id?
but I'm new to jquery so I don't know how to do it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
  $('#' + <%= select_install_type.ClientID %>).change(function () {
            var selected = $(this).val();
  }
```

Or you can get the selected option's id:

```
  $('#' + <%= select_install_type.ClientID %>).change(function () {
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').prop("id");
  }
```

<kbd>**[jQuery Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/RF35g/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second option worked :) , I think the first option is essantially the same code I've written, right?

Comment: Yes..I just stated the options.. :)